# Convert vector of strings into hash-map in Clojure

Tags: data-structures, clojure, data-transform

I have the following data structure:

`["a 1" "b 2" "c 3"]`

How can I transform that into a hash-map?

I want the following data structure:

`{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}`

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: @cfrick Thanks for you suggestion. I did not have any meaningful code or errors to show. As I'm brand new to Clojure, my attempts were futile and would not add any meaningful value to the question—It would only have cluttered up the question with unnecessary verbiage. I opted for succinctness, for ease of reading and to respect peoples' time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`clojure.string/split`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/split) and then use [`keyword`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keyword) and `Integer/parseInt`:

```
(->> ["a 1" "b 2" "c 3"]
     (map #(clojure.string/split % #" "))
     (map (fn [[k v]] [(keyword k) (Integer/parseInt v)]))
     (into {}))
=> {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3}
```

Answer (score 3):

and one more :)

```
(->> ["a 1" "b 2" "c 3"]
     (clojure.pprint/cl-format nil "{~{:~a ~}}")
     clojure.edn/read-string)

;;=> {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

```clj
(into {}
      (map #(clojure.edn/read-string (str "[:" % "]")))
      ["a 1" "b 2" "c 3"])
;; => {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(def x ["a 1" "b 2" "c 3"])
```

```
(clojure.edn/read-string (str "{:" (clojure.string/join " :" x) "}"))
;;=> {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3}
```